# Friendly_id still showing user id in the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I am trying to use the Friendly_id gem and it works for user edit but not user show page. On the user show page it still uses the user id instead of the user_name which is the slug. I am not sure what my mistake is thank you for all the help.

routes

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :user_name, use: :slugged
end
```

user_controller

```
def edit
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
end

def show
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: Could you add the whole controller?

Comment: Possibly the redirect or the link to the show action is wrong.

Comment: Yes thank you. you were correct the redirect was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the official document of [friendly_id](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html), i guessed that you missed this line: `extend FriendlyId`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId 
  friendly_id :user_name, use: :slugged
end
```

Comment: I had that i just forgot to add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

For me I solve it by removing use: :slugged

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :user_name
end
```